# Provide authentication credentials to angular $http.post

Tags: django, angularjs, http

I am using django-rest-framework for my API. In order to post data to my API, a user has to first login with his credentials.

In command line posting looks something like this:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/ -d "code=print 789" -u username:password

{"id": 5, "owner": "tom", "title": "foo", "code": "print 789", "linenos": false, "language": "python", "style": "friendly"}
```

Now, I am trying to post data with angularjs. Here is the code:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/snippets/', self.newSnippet)
     .then(fetchSnippets())
     .then(function (response) {
          self.newSnippet = {};
     })
```

Of course, it did not allow me to post this data as I did not login.

**Question:**

How do I send user credentials with this $http.post like I did with curl in command line (-u username:password)?

Comment: try django-swagger to test your rest-api

Comment: Authentication in a REST environment requires some particular attention. Have a look at the DRF doc: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/. You could also directly call a login view if this API is available on your server (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTTP Basic Authentication, put this before your request:

```
encodedCredentials = Base64.encode('username' + ':' + 'password');
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encodedCredentials;
```

You also need to have `Base64` implemented or get it from some lib.

Comment: If it's basic authentication can't you just add it to the URL ?

Comment: Well, I think it is not good idea to do this. And I think this example is not good too, because it will be more better to use JWT or something else with django-rest-framework, when you provide your credentials only once to get this token.